# is there any solution for this landscape problem?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

hi Im using android studio for a project when i turn landscape mode the blue image doesnt fill all the screen is there any solutions[image]

Comment: Your height is wrap_content. Try to set it to match parent?

Comment: it wont work it will fill all the screen i found this solution for landscape mode   android:scaleType="fitXY" thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

two way to solve :

1. write android:layout_height="match_parent" for the ImageView
2. create another layout Exactly with the "activity_main" name, just during creating the layout set the Orientation Qualifier in landScape and set the imageView full screen.